# How to use intern as a phase (functional tests) in my continuos integration system (jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, functional-testing, intern

**Background:**

- I am trying to setup a CI system based on Jenkins.
- I am running functional tests using intern.
- The result of executing the functional test suite (either a pass or fail) is one of the stages in the build pipeline.

**Problem**

Is it possible to have jenkins and intern play together?

In particular - when intern executes the functional test suite:

When it fails - the build fails.

When it passes - the build passes.

- To my knowledge, (and i have conducted an exhaustive search) There is no documentation that suggests this is possible, however, I would assume it is.  If anyone has tried this, failed, succeeded, given up -- anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: thanks - i will update this question after reading.

Comment: I have read the article.  Great read.  I must say I have not tried 'anything'. While I completely support and agree with the your and the author's suggestions on stackoverflow etiquette, it is just a suggestion - not a rule - and therefore is not appropriate in all cases.  I was hoping for a reference to another document or even a simple hint at where to begin looking.  What I failed to mention is that the project I am working on is in an early stage where we are 'surveying the field' for the right tools, given our needs.

Comment: As a result, the cost of doing a deep dive and trying things out  simply does not scale when you are surveying.  I think my question does need a statement that reads -- 'Is it possible to have jenkins and intern play together?'

Comment: [so] is a place to get specific answers about specific questions. That _is_ a rule. It's not a place to go to get a hint. When you have a specific question, then please come back and get the answer. In the meantime, this is the wrong place for your question.

Comment: With all due respect Mr. Saunders - I recognize your contributions to this community - I do not agree with your comment in particular that this is the wrong place for my question.  I've read the 'about' page after your response and I feel that my question is indeed appropriate and sufficient.  I will certainly take your comment into consideration going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Intern returns proper exit codes so all you have to do in Jenkins is execute it as a build step and it works fine. There is a link to a blog that provides detailed information about this in the [Intern documentation](http://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki).